# Adding class with jQuery but make sure it uses all the tags after the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wasn't sure how to word this in the title but lets say you have something set out like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tabp1').show();
        $('#tabp2').hide();
        $('#tabp3').hide();
        $('#tab1').addClass("activeTab");
        $('#tab1').css("activeTab");
    })

    function tab1(){
        $('#tabp1').show();
        $('#tabp2').hide();
        $('#tabp3').hide();
        $('#tab1').addClass("activeTab"); // add class activeTab to show active
        $('#tab2').removeClass("activeTab"); // remove the class from the pre selected ones
        $('#tab3').removeClass("activeTab"); // remove the class from the pre selected ones
    }
    function tab2(){
        $('#tabp2').show();
        $('#tabp1').hide();
        $('#tabp3').hide();
        $('#tab1').removeClass("activeTab"); // remove the class from the pre selected ones
        $('#tab2').addClass("activeTab"); // add class activeTab to show active
        $('#tab3').removeClass("activeTab"); // remove the class from the pre selected ones
    }
    function tab3(){
        $('#tabp1').hide();
        $('#tabp3').show();
        $('#tabp2').hide();
        $('#tab1').removeClass("activeTab"); // remove the class from the pre selected ones
        $('#tab2').removeClass("activeTab"); // remove the class from the pre selected ones
        $('#tab3').addClass("activeTab"); // add class activeTab to show active
    }

</script>
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="table-tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li id="tab1" class="tab"><a onClick="tab1();">Accommodation</a></li>
                    <li id="tab2" class="tab"><a onClick="tab2();">Special Offers</a></li>
                    <li id="tab3" class="tab"><a onClick="tab3();">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabp1">Tab 1:  nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta 
                    nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus</div>

                <div id="tabp2">Tab 2 content</div>

                <div id="tabp3">This one here is tab 3, full of Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam 
                    erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, 
                    quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end table tabs -->
```

finally, the CSS:

```css
  #content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li.oldTab{
    /* sets background and text color */
}

#content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li.activeTab a{
    color: white;
}

#content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li.activeTab{
    background-color: #015f01;
}
#content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li.tab a{
    color: black;
}

#content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li.tab{
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
}
```

I need the javascript to not only select the:

```css
#content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li.activeTab
```

But also:

```css
#content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li.activeTab a
```

This should be possible, any ideas?

Just to clarify the problem here:

The javascript applies the class activeTab  correctly, however I need the text to be white on that, so when i selected a (after the active tab) and changed color to white, it doesnt apply it.

interesting change, I have changed my text text size on the anchor attribute and it changed the size, so im thinking its an issue with the color

Comment: Hi dude, not sure what you're asking. Obviously something isn't working. Can you replicate the issue on http://jsfiddle.net or point us towards a working example and tell us what the problem is? Thanks

Comment: thanks for the comment, im doing it now :)

Comment: cool, let me know when you've done it. :)

Comment: it isnt using the jQuery in CSS fiddle, I cant find the latest version of jQ hosted on google :S

Comment: I have updated the bottom of my OP :) I dont know if that clears it up?

Comment: @zomboble I cleared up your code a little. Its untested but should work. http://jsfiddle.net/rAGRa/1/ . Basically I have removed unneeded lines to reduce your code down

Comment: Your code is quite lengthy and quite complicated. I think I understand your problem, the a links aren't changing colour when you're clicking on the links right?

Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UaZKt/ I have implemented a really simple version of what I think you're trying to achieve. It is using jQuery 1.7.2 (which you can select on the left hand side of jsFiddle).

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need anything explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming you select an "#table-tabs ul li a":

```
$("#table-tabs ul li a").click( function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

$(this).parent().toggleClass('tab activeTab'); //Remove class tab, add class activeTab

});
```

Comment: Where would that go? Surly it cant be to select the tab as its an element?

Comment: The full left half of this selector is completely useless seeing as ids must be unique within a document

Answer (score 2):

these two selectors are equally precise which means the last declared one will be used

```
#content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li.activeTab a{
    color: white;
}

#content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li.tab a{
    color: black;
}
```

You can fix it by using a default color which gets overridden when active

```
/* white when active (now more precise because of li.activeTab */
#content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li.activeTab a{
    color: white;
}
/* default black */
#content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li a{
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change, just place !important with color, it will fix it

```
#content-left #mainLeftContent #table-tabs ul li.activeTab a{
    color: white !important;
}
```

check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ENS8N/

Answer (score 0):

It works on my side after tweaking your CSS, you do not have to add all that extra css referencing. Just keep it simple like this, it's working perfectly on my side.

```
<style type="text/css">
li.oldTab{
    /* sets background and text color */
}

li.tab a{
    color: black;
}

li.tab{
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
}
li.activeTab a{
    color: white;
}

li.activeTab{
    background: #999;
}
</style>
```